# Google email markup: only certain merchant name works

Tags: email, haml, microdata, google-schemas

I'm trying to include some metadata on emails that get sent out on order receipts.

Only certain merchant names seem to be working, such as "Amazon.com", "Ebay.com", and a few others. I want to put in my own. Here's an example:

Google email markup: only certain merchant name works:

```
  %div{:itemscope => "", :itemtype => "http://schema.org/Order"}
    %div{:itemprop => "merchant", :itemscope => "", :itemtype => "http://schema.org/Organization"}
      %meta{:content => "Amazon.com", :itemprop => "name"}/
```

I'd like the content part of the name meta tag to be anything I like. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use your own custom organization like "MyStore.com"?

Comment: @austin809 You should be able to put whatever you want, the documentation states that it accepts a string for merchant (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/order#specification).